# onsenui ons-navigator内のpushPageでパラメータを渡したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

お世話になります。
ons-toolbarでページ移行するappを開発中なのですが、

ons-listから詳細ページに移行する際にパラメータを渡したいのですが、
urlにパラメータを付加することは可能でしょうか？
またその際移行先のページでのパラメータの呼び出しはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

urlパラメータが使えない場合はページ移行の際に変数を送る方法はありましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ページネーションを担っているのはons-toolbarではなくons-navigatorですので、誤解の生じないようタイトル等修正をご検討ください。

Comment: citherさん＞タイトルを修正しました＞＿＜

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLにパラメータを渡すやり方はうまくいかないと思います。
代わりに、`pushPage()`の第二引数にオプションを渡し、目的ページで`getCurrentPage()`を呼んで受け取る方法があります。

```js
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('listController', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {id: 1, title: 'item1'},
    {id: 2, title: 'item2'},
    {id: 3, title: 'item3'},
    {id: 4, title: 'item4'},
  ];
})
.controller('detailController', function($scope){
  var options = $scope.nav.getCurrentPage().options;
  $scope.item = options.item;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-navigator page="list.html" var="nav"></ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="list.html">
  <ons-page ng-controller="listController">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center">list</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="nav.pushPage('detail.html', {item: item})">
        {{item.title}}
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="detail.html">
  <ons-page ng-controller="detailController">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center">{{item.title}}</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: pushPage()に第二引数をつけれるのですね！
とても参考になりました。
これで思い描いていた動きが実現できそうです。

Comment: 余談なのですが、pushPage()に引数ではなく直接、値を渡す事も出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: 今ひとつ質問の意図がつかめないので別な言い方をしてもらえますか。どのように値を渡すことを想定していますか？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。現在試行錯誤中でして、煮詰まりましたら再度質問させていただきます。