# OnsenUIのons-navigatorを使いpushPageで続けて次のページにパラメータを渡したい場合にどうするか

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

お世話になります。
OnsenUIのons-navigatorを使いpushPageで次のページにパラメータを渡したい場合、

[onsenui ons-navigator内のpushPageでパラメータを渡したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15022/onsenui-ons-navigator%E5%86%85%E3%81%AEpushpage%E3%81%A7%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/15025#15025)

こちらの記事を参考にパラメータを引き渡す事はできたのですが、続けて更にその次のページに引き渡す方法がわからないので教えて下さい。

```
var module = ons.bootstrap();
module.controller('answerController', function($scope){
  var options = $scope.myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options;
  if(options.correct == 1){
    $scope.counter = options.counter+1;
  }else{
    $scope.counter = options.counter;
  }
});
```

この形で成否の正答数を次のページに引き渡したかったのですが

```
<a href="#" onClick="myNavigator.pushPage('nextpage.html', {correct:1,counter:AAAA})">正解の方</a>
<a href="#" onClick="myNavigator.pushPage('nextpage.html', {correct:0,counter:AAAA})">不正解の方</a>
```

上記AAAAの部分を{{counter}}という形にしても変換されないのですし、シングルクォーテーションで囲っても変換されない為、次のページにパラメータが渡りません。
わかる方ご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angularのデータを用いる場合、`onClick`ではなく`ng-click`を使ってください。

```
<a href="#" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('nextpage.html', {correct:1,counter:counter})">正解の方</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('nextpage.html', {correct:0,counter:counter})">不正解の方</a>
```