# monaca/onsen-ui で一覧ページのデータを詳細ページで使いたい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

現在Monaca/onsen-uiにてアプリ開発をしております。
一覧ページで取得したデータを詳細ページでも使いたいのですがうまくいかなくて困っております。

```js
var app = ons.bootstrap();
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q',
  function($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.MyDelegate = {
      configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
        if (!itemScope.item) {
          itemScope.canceler = $q.defer();
          itemScope.item = {
            name: '',
            add: '',
            desc: '',
            ph: ''
          };
          $http.get('http://hoge.com/hoge.php', {
            timeout: itemScope.canceler.promise
          }).success(function(data) {

            itemScope.item.name = data[index].name;
            itemScope.item.add = data[index].add;
            itemScope.item.desc = data[index].desc;
            itemScope.item.ph = data[index].ph;
          }).error(function() {
            itemScope.item.name = 'データはありません！';
          });
        }
      },
      calculateItemHeight: function(index) {
        return 91;
      },
      countItems: function() {
        return 1000;
      }
    };
  }
])
```

上記のようにデータベースよりデータを取得し

```html
<ons-template id="hoge.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" ons-lazy-repeat="MyDelegate" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('hogehoge.html')">
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="80px">
          <img ng-src="http://hoge.com/images/{{item.ph}}" class="item-thum"></img>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
          <header>
            <div ng-show="item.name==''">
              <p><span style='opacity: 0.7;'><ons-icon icon='fa-spinner' spin='true'></ons-icon> Loading list...</p></span>
            </div>
            <span class="item-title">{{item.name}}</span>
          </header>
          <p class="item-desc">
            <ons-icon icon="fa-map-marker" style="padding-right:5px"></ons-icon>{{ item.add }}</p>
          <p class="item-desc">{{ item.desc }}</p>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

一覧ページを表示してng-clickで詳細ページにページ遷移しています。

詳細ページに遷移した際に一覧ページで取得したデータを使用したいですがうまくいきません。
どなたか、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: [onsenui ons-navigator内のpushPageでパラメータを渡したい](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15022/onsenui-ons-navigator%E5%86%85%E3%81%AEpushpage%E3%81%A7%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)というやり方と`AngularJS`を利用するのであれば、`factory`や`value`を使うやり方もあります。

Comment: onsenui ons-navigator内のpushPageでパラメータを渡したいというやり方でうまく実装できました。ありがとうございました。